# Does Python have any features which can be used for encapsulating private data?

Tags: object-oriented, python, language-design

Usually in **OOP** world we are told that modularity is a good practice and keeping loose coupling between module is a great thing. Encapsulation helps us achieve this loose coupling.

In **Java** encapsulation is achieved via [access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), in **Ruby** we have stricter rules via [attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor).

But what about Python? I see that I can't hide my fields or methods except using tricks like `__` in front of names. Is this the correct / only way to achieve encapsulation in Python?

Comment: why do you feel like you need to hide your fields or methods?

Comment: @BryanOakley for the same reason we do in Java or Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the following C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        Foo(int x): x(x) {}

        void printX() {
            cout << "My x is " << x << endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo foo(12);
    foo.printX(); // prints "My x is 12"

    //foo.x = 13; // error: ‘int Foo::x’ is private

    *((int*) &foo) = 14;
    foo.printX(); // prints "My x is 14"

    return 0;
}
```

I've broken the encapsulation by casting a pointer. Does that mean encapsulation is broken in C++? No - because no one in their right mind would do that! Cast at your own risk.

It's the same with Python - use fields prefixed with `_` at your own risk. Encapsulation is for safety - not for security. You don't put private keys in private fields and trust the encapsulation to prevent users from touching them. You use encapsulation to protect the users of your classes from internal implementation details - and if these users don't respect Python's convention it's their own damn problem.

Comment: Why this freedom in Python only? why not in Java or any statically typed language? Also, one thing seems quite disturbing to me that in python any client code can change the `Shape` of the object any time hence creating havoc.

Comment: The whole idea of encapsulation seems useless in python.If I agree to you because the power now lies in the hands of client code not in your hands.

Comment: If the client wants he can throw out entire classes and replace them by new ones. The Python philosophy is that we're all consenting adults and can use our own judgement.

Comment: "Encapsulation is for safety - not for security" — good one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@property` annotations to implement getters and setters à la Java or Ruby. These provide some form of encapsulation while still allowing users of your class to access attributes in a Pythonic way.

Say you have a class with a public-facing `name` attribute, but names needed to be under a certain length.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        if len(name) <= 3:
            self.name = name
        else:
            raise TypeError
```

In this case, the `name` value length is checked at instantiation but not thereafter; you could use a `_name` attribute and ugly `get_name()` and `set_name()` methods, but by using `@property` annotations as below, you can do validity checking for the attribute whenever it's set while still letting it be accessed in the conventional Python way, i.e. by means of expressions like `foo.name` and `foo.name = 'xyz'`.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, new_name: str):
        if len(new_name) <= 3:
            self._name = new_name
        else:
            raise TypeError
```

As Idan mentioned, `_`-prefixing of private methods/attributes is just a (strongly followed) convention and a user could still mangle the attribute value if they really wanted to, e.g. by `foo._name = 'abcdef'`.